# How can I query Neo4j by a user input value ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, input, neo4j, var

I am wondering why this code doesnt do what I want, and that is :

I have a input tag with id = 'input1', and when the user presses the search button, I want to take that value to specify the name in the neo4j query. 
But now I get empty brackets in my console ([]) instead of, for example, the node with name: Emil
This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<button onclick="myJsFunction()">Search</button>
```

```
              function myJsFunction(){


 var body = JSON.stringify({
        statements: [{
            statement: " MATCH (n {name: '" +  document.getElementById('input1').value + "´}) RETURN n"
        }]
    });
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
type: "POST",
data: body,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json"

})

      .done(function(result){
        console.log(result.results);

    })
    .fail(function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });
```

}

Any help would be appreciated cuz I am stuck for now.

Comment: Before answers start coming in, you realize that your users will be able to bypass your app and access your database directly, right?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Anybody can send a request (containing any query) to your database and access the data.

Comment: If the user's web browser is talking to your database, they'll be able to find the address to it with almost no work. They'll be able to run their own commands -- whatever commands they want -- against it.

Comment: The web browser should never talk to the database. That's what your server should be doing. If you want to use Javascript to talk to Neo4j, explore Node.JS.

Comment: Use parameters like {name} and a map with values from your input form, not query concatenation, you don't want to have injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

In your query the single quotes (for the name parameter) do not match. You are opening with [ ' ] but closing with [ ` ].

Comment: @user3660293 why exactly did you unaccept my answer?